# Any instance of key anywhere in a nested hash

Tags: ruby

Given a hash like so:

```
h = {
  "actual_amount" => 20,
  "otherkey" => "value",
  "otherkey2" => [{"actual_amount" => 30, "random_amount" => 45}]
}
```

where there are any number of layers of nesting, is there a simple way to pluck all the key-value pairs (or just the values) of the keys that are `actual_amount`?

Comment: Your "hash" is invalid.

Comment: Do you want to get the **key** if **val** has `actual_amount`? If so, try this `h.map{|k, v| p k if (v.is_a?(Array) && v.first["actual_amount"].present?)}`

Comment: Seems need use Recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed the values of keys are literals or arrays of hashes.

This question clearly calls for a recursive solution.

```
def amounts(h)
  h.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),a|
    case v
    when Array
      v.each { |g| a.concat amounts(g) }
    else
      a << v if k == "actual_amount"
    end
  end
end
```

Suppose

```
h = {
  "actual_amount"=>20,
  1=>2,
  2=>[
      { "actual_amount"=>30,
        3=>[
            { "actual_amount" => 40 },
            { 4=>5 }
           ]
      },
      { 5=>6 }
     ]
}
```

then

```
amounts(h)
  #=> [20, 30, 40]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the hash, provided by Cary, as an input:

```
▶ flatten = ->(inp) do
▷   [*(inp.respond_to?(:map) ? inp.map(&:flatten) : inp)]
▷ end
▶ res = flatten(h).first
▶ res.select.with_index do |_, i|
▷   i > 0 && res[i - 1] == 'actual_amount'
▷ end
#⇒ [20, 30, 40]
```